# How to run a job after MR is approved, but reject MR, if the job failed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like some automated checks were done after MR is approved, because for those checks pipeline has to access protected variables.

If these checks fail, MR should be rejected.

In other words the desired sequence should be this:

MR created -> build -> run tests -> MR approved (no malicious exposure of protected variables)-> merged to protected branch -> run checks -> rollback on failure.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the Gitlab API and adding two new jobs at the end of the pipeline.

The **when** keyword is one of the many ways to control which jobs are executed in a pipeline. Two of the available `when` options will be useful here. The first job to put at the end of your pipeline will be for the success condition:

```
approve_merge_request:
  stage: approve_merge_request
  when: on_success
  script:
    - # this will call the Gitlab Merge Requests API and approve it. More on this below
```

This parameter to `when` is actually the default, so you could leave the `when` off of this step and it would still work. I added it here for clarity. What it means is that this job will only run if every other job in the pipeline passed. However, if a job fails but has the `allow_failure: true` attribute, it is still considered a pass and this job will run (there's currently no way to detect that some jobs were allowed to fail in a `when` condition). In addition, jobs with `when: manual` that haven't run are considered passed, even though it could later fail. `when: manual` means the job has to be started by an API call or UI interaction by a user.

The second job will handle our failure condition:

```
reject_merge_request:
  stage: approve_merge_request
  when: on_failure
  script:
    - # this will call the Gitlab Merge Requests API and reject it. More on this below
```

This parameter to `when` means that this job will only run if at least one job prior to this has failed, and doesn't have `allow_failure: true`.

The **Merge Requests API** can be used to approve, reject, comment on, and merge a Merge Request, among other options. The full documentation is available here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html. Unfortunately, the API to use the "approvals" feature of merge requests is available only to paying customers, but you can still get a similar result without the approvals.

You can approve a Merge Request (note, this doesn't merge it, that's "accepting" the merge request. Also, this is a paid feature so is only available to Starter or Bronze customers and above) with the API operation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#approve-merge-request. After you approve the Merge Request, you probably want to accept it, which will merge the source branch into the target branch. That operation is outlined below.

You can get all of the required ids from the predefined variables Gitlab CI gives you. The project ID can be retrieved from the variable `$CI_PROJECT_ID`. The Merge Request IID is different from the Merge Request ID. The "ID" version is a unique ID across your entire Gitlab instance, and the "IID" version is specific to the project it's in. For this operation we need the IID. You can get that with the variable `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID`. You should check that each variable exists before trying to use it as it will cause issues in your API call. It will exist for all pipelines associated with a Merge Request that is open.

There isn't equivalent functionality in Gitlab Merge Requests to "reject" other than commenting and closing, which I outline below.

If you're not a paid customer, or you want to accept and merge the request, you want to use the Accept Merge Request operation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr. This uses the same variables from above.

Finally, if you're not a paid user but still want to "reject" the merge request, you can use the Notes API to add a comment to the Merge Request. The operation to add a comment to a merge request is here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#accept-mr.

After commenting, if you want to close the merge request, you can do so with the Update MR operation and setting the `state_event` to `close`: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr

Comment: The question was not how to automatically approve a merge request. He was asking how to make the merge-to-master trigger another job.